# Mac OS Clipboard manager with dropdown like Ditto

Tags: clipboard

Does anyone know a clipboard manager for macOS that can be triggered via keyboard?
I used Windows for a while and found this wonderful clipboard manager, [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/),
which has a shortcut (CTRL + ~) and had the same shortcut for navigating through all my items in the clipboard history. Pressing again `~` would go to the previous item in the history, and releasing `CTRL` key would trigger a dump of that value at the position of the current cursor(s).
I find that workflow just perfect and I want to recreate it somehow for mac.
Maybe write myself some utility in java/python/rust/jai? Maybe someone knows some good libraries.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> a clipboard manager for macOS that can be triggered via keyboard?

I wanted to get the same thing for some time now,

The latest free one that has this same description is named:

**Flycut**

Not the best-looking one, but its functionalities are good enough for me.

Comment: has a hotkey that can be customized too.